# What is the best approach to manage shared and unshared content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get views like the following scheme:

[image]

I have a common header with common text for all the views, but different icon per model and inside each model differents buttons per action.

I start rendering a `_header` in `application.html.erb` but I don't know if is the best approach to change the icons per Controller view and how to change content inside the header per Controller action.

I want to know what is the 'railistic' way to get it.

Comment: save you images with your controller name, suppose category.img, product.img,  then based on params `#{controller.name}.img`

Comment: Thanks @Sontya. I'm using Font Awesome for the icons... And the Buttons for each Controller Action ?. There are different number of them and different actions.

Comment: Same thing you can try with buttons too, suppose `<%= link_to 'Button #{params[:action]}'`, `params[:action]+_+#{param[:controller]}+_path, method: :post %>`
or you can use button_to

`<%= button_to 'Button #{params[:action]}',  params[:action]+_+#{param[:controller]}+_path, method: :post %>`

Comment: Above is just the example how you can do this, as I don't know your exact actions and button name

Comment: @Sontya, I started as you say, but the problem is that each Controller Action View has to have different number or buttons now. For example, for `product/index.html.erb` there are 3 Buttons, for `product/new.html.erb` there are 2 buttons, and so on.

Comment: for your logos I have some other idea to save in database the logos for each categories you have then you can say `= image_tag current_user.category.logo.url`

Comment: In case of buttons, call different partials based on your controller action. Suppose `product/index.html.erb` called, then render `_index_buttons` partial which will have 3 buttons and if `product/new.html.erb` called then render `_new_buttons` partial which will have 2 buttons

Comment: to achieve this `= image_tag current_user.category.logo.url` suppose category is you model then in that `has_attachment :logo, :styles => { :medium => "200x200>", :small => "50x50" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions. I chose the second one:

**A: Partial Layouts:**

in `products/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= render layout: 'shared/admin_header' do %>
  <%= render layout: 'shared/header_main' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-tag fa-fw"></i>
   <% end %>
   <%= render layout: 'shared/header_right' do %>
     <%= link_to "Add a product", new_admin_product_path, class: ["btn", "btn-primary", "pull-right"] %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in `shared/admin_header.html.erb`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top admin-header">
  <%= yield %>
</nav>
```

in `shared/_header_main.html.erb`:

```
<h1 class="header-main">
  <%= yield %>
</h1>
```

in `shared/_header_right.html.erb`:

```
<div class="header-right">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

**B: Using the `content_for` and multiple `yield` regions:**

in `application.html.erb`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top admin-header">
  <h1 class="header-main">
    <%= yield :header_main %>
  </h1>
  <div class="header-right">
    <%= yield :header_right%>
  </div>
</nav>
```

in `products/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= content_for :header_main do %>
  <i class="fa fa-tag fa-fw"></i>
<% end %>

<%= content_for :header_right do %>
  <%= link_to "Add a product", new_admin_product_path, class: ["btn", "btn-primary", "pull-right"] %>
  <%# MORE CONTENT %>
<% end %>
```